# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status') for offline users

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, offline, status

I made a userinfo command that display user's information like the custom statut, activites, ...

I have a problem, when i type my command for any offline user, the console return this message :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')
at UserInfoCommand.exec (D:\Developpement\FuzeBot\src\commands\misc\userinfo.js:26:46)
at CommandHandler.runCommand (D:\Developpement\FuzeBot\node_modules\discord-akairo\src\struct\commands\CommandHandler.js:1173:29)
at CommandHandler.handleDirectCommand (D:\Developpement\FuzeBot\node_modules\discord-akairo\src\struct\commands\CommandHandler.js:739:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async CommandHandler.handle (D:\Developpement\FuzeBot\node_modules\discord-akairo\src\struct\commands\CommandHandler.js:541:11)
```

I'm using akairo's framework and discord.js.

Here is userinfo.js :

```js
        const { Command } = require('discord-akairo');
    const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
    
    class UserInfoCommand extends Command {
        constructor() {
            super('userinfo', {
               aliases: ['userinfo', 'info'],
               description: 'Affiche les informations de l\'utilisateur',
               userPermissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR',
               clientPermissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR',
               channel: 'guild',
               args: [
                 {id: 'member', type: 'member', default: message => message.member },
               ]
            });
        }
        
        exec(message, args) {
         
          const getStatus = args.member.presence.status;
          const activities= [];
          
          for (const activity of args.member.presence.activities.values()) {
            console.log(activity);
            switch (activity.type) {
              case 'PLAYING':
                activities.push(`Joue à **${activity.name}**`);
                break;
              case 'LISTENING':
                if (args.bot) activities.push(`Écoute **${activity.name}**`);
                else activities.push(`Écoute **${activity.details}** de **${activity.state}**`);
                break;
              case 'WATCHING':
                activities.push(`Regarde **${activity.name}**`);
                break;
              case 'STREAMING':
                activities.push(`Stream **${activity.name}**`);
                break;
              case 'CUSTOM':
                var customStatus = activity.state;
                console.log(`------ ${customStatus} -------`);
                if(customStatus === ''){
                  var customStatus = '*Aucun statut pour le moment*';
                }
                break;
            }
          }
    
          switch (getStatus){
            case 'online':
              var status = "<:online:917793203523027024>";
            break;
            case 'idle':
              var status = "<:idle:917793108354297886>";
            break;
            case 'offline':
              var status = "<:offline:917793167691100242>";
            break;
            case 'dnd':
              var status = "<:dnd:917793482620420106>";
            break;
          }
    
          console.log(`------ ${activities.length} -------`);
          const embed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor("#FFD700")
          .setTitle(`<:user:916747116259463228>  **Informations sur l'utilisateur**`)
          .setThumbnail(args.member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
          .setDescription(`<@${args.member.id}> **(${args.member.user.tag})**`);
          console.log(status);
          if(status !== 'offline'){
            if(activities.length > 0){
              embed.addField('<:videogame:917781052003598366> Activité :', `${activities}`, true)
            }else{
              embed.addField('<:videogame:917781052003598366> Activité :', `*Aucune activité en cours*`, true)
            }
    
            if(!customStatus){
              embed.addField(` ${status} Statut :`, `*Aucun statut*`, true)
            }else{
              embed.addField(`${status} Statut :`, `${customStatus}`, true)
            }
          }
          return message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
    
        }}module.exports = UserInfoCommand;
```

I don't know how to solve it. Sorry for my bad english btw. It happens only when user is offline...

Comment: It would be a better idea to declare `status` outside of the switch statement, and log it later to see what you come up with.

Comment: I believe that the problem is at  at the line `const getStatus = args.member.presence.status;` but I can't be sure by just looking at the above code. If you are sure that this happens when the user is offline changing the line to `const getStatus = args.member.presence.status || 'offline';` will probably make it work, but this is only a workaround and you should better find out why the status is not being passed to the exec function

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still not working.. I tried but i've got the same error. It seems like when user is offline, no data is sent ...

Answer (score 1):

```
const getStatus = args.member?.presence?.status;
```

this would address the error produced by the only instance of addressing a "status" property when it is not set. But then the question is, why is it not set?

It might be that you will have to:

```
const getStatus = args.member?.presence?.status ?? 'offline';
```

but, this is assuming that you won't have access to the same object elsewhere in the graph when they are offline. So, I would add a `console.log(args)` to your *offline* switch case, so you can look for an alternative location in that case

Comment: Thank for your answer. Unfortunately it still not working, besides, i can't console log anything because my bot just stop and only show the error ..

Comment: there must be a way to debug bots in your environment. :) I would consider researching that to be more important than anything else. if you are getting _the same error_, then you failed to update your code or else it is not coming from the code that you provided. please ensure it is executing your changed code, and if so then identify other code containing "x.y.status"